# Can't use cache:true with OAuth.initialize

Tags: eclipse, oauth

I am trying to use OAuth according to https://oauth.io/docs/api in an android eclipse app.

```
import io.oauth.*;
.....
final OAuth o = new OAuth(this);
o.initialize(KEY);
```

works fine.

However, I want to use the cache functionality in order not to log on every time, so I try

```
o.initialize(KEY, {cache: true});
```

Unfortunately this won't compile. I get

```
"Multiple markers at this line
  -Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
  -Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"
```

As you can tell I am an android and Eclipse newbie, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The public key is the only argument used for the initialize method.
The correct method that accepts the cache object as an argument is popup.

Example:

```js
OAuth.initialize('x9x9x9x9x9'); //OAuth.io public key

var promise = OAuth.popup('google_mail', {cache: true});

promise.done(function (result) {
    // make API calls
});

promise.fail(function (error) {
    // handle errors
});
```